# Selenium not copying exact text from excel to date textbox

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

I am trying to retrieve date from excel and use  `send_keys()` function to enter it into a textbox. The date im retrieving from excel is `4/10/2019` but when i run my script, the result shown is `20191004000000`.
May i know, how can i solve this or is there any other way of entering `date` instead of using `send_key()` ? I've seen someone using

```
IJavaScriptExecutor jse = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
jse.ExecuteScript($"arguments[0].value='{employmentParam.StartDate}';", wb);
```

to enter value, but has no idea what it does.

I tried without adding the `str()` around `date`, but error became  `object of type 'datetime.datetime' has no len()`

Here I read date from excel

```
date = XLUtlis.readData(path, 'BO', r, 19)
```

Here I write `date` into `textbox`

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="mainContentHolder_dtlNew_txtOriginalEsd"]').send_keys(str(date))
```

**EDIT:**

I figured out that when the script copy from excel, it somehow copied `2019-10-04 00:00:00` , but when it is entered through `send_keys()`, it neglected special signs such as  `-   :`. Any idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to convert the data type from datetime to string.
And then you can use send_keys with the string value.
According to my experience, I recommend use string type to set values of input elements.

```
start_date = employmentParam.StartDate.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="mainContentHolder_dtlNew_txtOriginalEsd"]').send_keys(start_date)
```